# Best way to keep ObservableCollection and ObjectContext in sync?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, objectcontext

I have window with a listbox bound to an ObservableCollection of People (a set of entity framework objects that I retrieve in response to a users query: a search box), i then have functions such as Edit, Delete and Add New. At the moment i am simply making sure that each time i Add or Remove something from the Database that i also work with the OC. Is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks,
Kohan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that you may need to manage the OC youself when it comes to EF manipulations. For example, when you Add a new item to DB

```
private bool AddItems(Item item)
{
    bool addSucceed = false;

    // Do adding ...

    if(addSucceed)
        MyObservableCollection.Remove(item)
    else
        // Error notificaiton here.
}
```

Hope that helps.